# Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1

Tags: maven, selenium, teamcity

I have a Maven project and uploaded it to SubVersion. For Continutuous Integration we are using Team City. I did configure a build in Team City and tried to run my project through Team City. I am getting the following error when I run the build. Please advise.

[com.testing:MavenTestUC] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 (C:\Users\autobuild.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.4.1\maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar): error in opening zip file

Comment: Check the console output during the build. I assume there are WARNING's about download issues/checksum validation issues etc. Furthermore maven-clean-plugin 2.4.1 is a little bit out of date...current version 2.6.1.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the downloaded artifact is corrupt. Try removing the following directory and retrying:

```
C:\Users\autobuild.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.4.1
```